# Why MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener is called when resume activity?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have an activity (A), it has a VideoView. I setup video view with onPrepareListener. When I start new activity (B) from A. After that, I come back to A from B, all element in onPrepared is called??? Why it happen??? So I'm sorry my english not good, thank you :D

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class));
            }
        });

        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(
                "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Charlize Theron's Variety Cover Shoot - Behind the Scenes.3gpp");
        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer m) {
                Log.i("test", m.toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: simple example above

Comment: You call it in onCreate? or onResume?

Comment: Try set Log in onCreate Activity A. If you back from B to A, method onCreate Activity A is called. Check ***Don't keep Activity*** on Device

Comment: All is called in onCreate, back from B to A, method onCreate sure not called :3

Comment: Check **Don't keep Activity** on Device

Comment: I checked, you can create a simple example, it will happen same my problem